# Other websites can't upload images from my site when I am using redirects

Tags: php, image, redirect, upload, http-headers

I have a website that has images with urls like this:

```
http://mysite.com/image1.jpg
```

My server uses php to do a redirect to a subdomain which contains the actual file, like this:

```
header('Location: http://images.mysite.com/image1.jpg');
```

This works fine for almost all purposes, like in an img tag or when saving the file locally.  The two urls are essentially equivalent for these purposes.  However, when I go to a site with an image uploader, like tumblr or imgur, and I try to upload the first url, it fails (saying "Error uploading photo" or  "Image format not supported, or image is corrupt.").

Is there a way to make this work?  I tried sending different status headers but they didn't help.

**EDIT:**

As suggested, I could do this with an htaccess redirect or by opening the file and sending the content.  This would work fine except I don't want this to happen when users are using the files for other purposes, like embedding it in an img tag.  This is because my images.mysite.com domain is a cdn for hosting my image content, and it would defeat it's purpose if I had to reserve the content from my web server.  And htaccess is not viable because I wanted to run some php scripts when the first url is requested.

If I could somehow detect when it's being used through a file uploader, then I could handle the other cases separately.  But I don't think I can detect that, can I?

**EDIT 2 (SOLUTION):**

Okay, I did a hacky compromise: it turns out that upload requests generally don't have an "accept_charset" parameter in the header, whereas embed requests do.  Using this I can detect when an image is being requested to be uploaded, and then I download that image and send out the content.  Not a rock-solid solution, but it works well enough.  Thanks guys!

Comment: They may be equivalent for end users, but the image uploaders are expecting a file, not a redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that your image uploader site doesn't follow the redirection you made. So, to make it works, instead of having a redirection, you should open your distant file and send its content.

Comment: I'm not 100% on this, but wouldn't .htaccess rewrites possibly be usable?

Comment: Yes, url rewriting should do the work. In fact it doesn't send any header redirection to the client.

Comment: htaccess will work but I wanted to do some php stuff during the redirect (like logging and other stuff).

Comment: .htaccess will do the exact same header-redirect like he wants to do, except the result code.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make this work, because the image upload services expect an actual image file, they do not follow any redirects.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use standard result code (200 - OK) with header-redirects.

Have a look at [this tutorial about how to send result codes](http://ditio.net/2008/10/04/php-redirect-header-location/).

Answer (score 1):

As other posters have said, image upload services read the data returned by your url

```
http://mysite.com/image1.jpg
```

as an image file - which is why the redirect confuses these services.

Instead of a redirect, why not use a PHP script that reads the image from the external source, and then prints out the binary data? You can accomplish this with an .htaccess file that looks for anything with ".jpg" in the request.

Comment: That would work but then it would do that for every request (not just file uploads), which would defeat the purpose of having it hosted on a  subdomain (which is a cdn).  If I could have this only happen for file uploads, it would be great, but a lot of people will also be embedding the images in img tags, and I don't want to redownload all of the images from my cdn to my server every time.

Comment: In that case you can do something like http://mysite.com/upload/image1.jpg will output the data and http://mysite.com/image1.jpg will do a redirect.